# Checking a DateTime which is part of a larger nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, let's call it 'tblData'. which has a field called 'details' which is a nvarchar(4000). in this field there might be a text like such : 
'blah blah ## 12/08/1982 ## blah blah'. the part that starts and ends in '##' might or might not exist.

I need to make a select statement with a where clause which will not return a row that has '## [date] ##' that is in the future. if the '## [date] ##' part does not exist, return the row.

is this possible to do without using a function?
and if I have to use a function, some sample code could come in handy as I barely know any tsql... 
10x alot!

Answer (score 2):

This is quite difficult to do in SQL.  You *can* do it, by extracting the date, and converting it.  But, SQL Server does not have great string manipulation functions.

The following extracts the date:

```
(case when details like '% [0-9]0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %'
      then substring(details,
                     patindex('% [0-9]0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %',
                              details) + 1, 10)
end)
```

So, you can put this into a `where` clause as:

```
where details not like '% [0-9]0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %' or
      convert(date,
              (case when details like '% [0-9]0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %'
                    then substring(details,
                                   patindex('% [0-9]0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %',
                                   details) + 1, 10),
               end), 101) <= getdate();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from tblData where details not like '%## ??/??/???? ##%'
```

Comment: quote: `which will not return a row that has '## [date] ##' that is in the future`. And tsql doesn't have `?` in `like`.

Comment: do you mean that you want to return only the rows with date <= the current date ? if yes, i have a question: 
is the date part location fixed inside the field details ? or it might come randomly ?